# How do I create specific quantities for specific products within Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, product-quantity

I've got a few products where I need the quantities for a specific product to start at a number, 240 for example and then the customer can select in intervals of 240, and for a different product, say 100 units. I need a way to separate a list of quantities for separate products.

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. Can you show us what have you tried on your own?

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the documentation related to InventoryItem endpoints which leads to InventoryLevel endpoints. Once you get a handle on Locations, you are free to set inventory levels. Note that setting explicit amounts is no longer the fashion, instead you ask how much is there, and then modify that amount with a delta change.

So if you ask for a product's variant level, and it tells you the current availability is 0, your delta might be +240.